# Modification by Community to question in Recently active tab

Tags: discussion, questions, community-user

I was reading the questions on the *Recently Active* tab which I don't often do (I usually look up the newest questions tab) and found this.

[image]

But I had viewed the question just a few minutes before that and after this so-called modification by the Community, I re-viewed the question and found it exactly the same.
This is the second time I am seeing this and that is why I want to know what is this modification done by the Community?

Is it just to bring an old question into the recently active part or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an overwhelming majority of cases, this is the bump on old unanswered questions that ACuriousMind describes.

In some cases, though, this can represent actual alterations. This includes edits suggested by anonymous visitors, which are then [owned by the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user). As a quick way to tell the difference, look on the upper right-hand corner of the page, for the metrics bit.

```
Asked   9 Months Ago
Viewed  116 Times
Active  Today
```

The word `Today` (or some date) is a hyperlink that will take you to the most recent activity on the thread. If it's a community-user bump, it will send you to the top of the page. If it's an actual edit it will take you there.

Comment: TIL about another hidden hyperlink.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, there's a gazillion of them around and a lot of them are not really that discoverable. Ditto for tooltips. Another alternative is the `modified 22 min ago` on the front page (as per the image on the OP). (Somewhat easier to discover, but still worth mentioning now we're at this.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, exactly, this is an automatized bump of old unanswered questions. The relevant conditions for this to happen are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/263383) on meta.SE.